# Accurate IndexOB and IndexMA passes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, masking, render-passes

I'm trying to get an **accurate index pass** for compositing. My geometry *(a window in this case)* consists of straight lines and it would be nice to have a perfect mask for color correction. As you can see **Anti-Aliasing is enabled**, but there are still some weird pixels:

[image]

Until now my workaround was to **blur the image**, but in this case straight lines are key to work with. How to achieve this? Is there a render **setting to prevent the noise** or make it less noisy?

Comment: add a additional layer that has nothing but the index pass, and see if its output is  better

Comment: Thanks @Chebhou. Already tried, but this can't be a permanent solution. What if I need more than 20 id passes?

Comment: you would use one layer just for  index pass ( one layer for all indexes ), not each object or material with its layer

Comment: @Chebhou Mhhh. I'm searching for a solid solution - using IndexOB makes more sense than using render layers.

Comment: [is that what you have tried](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/87218) ?

Comment: @Chebhou looks Interesting, I will try it.

Comment: @Chebhou unfortunately the same result. I think it's caused by _Depth of Field_ settings, I ever thought index ob passes ignores Depth settings, anyway still testing :)

Comment: if you are going to use two linked scenes then do a very high-res render of the index then scale it down

Comment: @Chebhou good point.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to render without DOF, and add it in during compositing in order to get clean IndexOB masks. Otherwise you'll probably have to separate via layers if you want in-camera DOF.

Alternatively, you could try [this solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/is-it-possible-to-create-a-render-layer-with-no-depth-of-field), which creates a second Scene, linked to your main scene with the camera DOF turned off. That way your second scene would have IndexOB masks with clean edges, and you can work with both scenes in the compositor. Would that solve your issue?

I'd be interested to know your final pipeline, I'm dubious that the clean masks would help you modify your DOF renders, but I would be interested to see more about it if it can.

Comment: Thanks Todd :) The image above almost has no depth, it's a really bright scene and F-Stop is at ca. 8, but it seems that this setting has a major impact. As I said, I ever thought index ob passes ignores the depth settings, because it's only a black and white calculation and gradients are not supported. In this context it makes no sense to provide this feature at all, but maybe it's not complete... I don't know if it's mathematically possible to calculate soft transitions like a mist pass, but I think we can create a cycles shader for this case. I'll try and let you know. Thanks again.