# Anti-aliasing options in the compositor (for Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

Blender Internal offers Anti Aliasing as part of its rendering. Cycles does not as it is sample based. Some ID masks or various passes can be badly aliased. What options are there to do anti aliasing in the compositor? I'm looking for node groups, but would also accept scripts or even outside programs.

Comment: What you are looking for to do correct compositor anti-aliasing is Full-AA-sampling. Some compositor nodes allow you to check anti-aliasing, but when you are compositing masks you will get border errors.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28917/accurate-indexob-and-indexma-passes