# How to use flat color shading with anti-aliasing for multi-materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, masking, id-mask

I've been searching a while now for a solution to render out a flat colored map for masking out objects in photoshop.

I found this very helpfull topic:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?387255-Surface-ID-Pass-in-Blender

Is there a way to combine this technique so that objects with the same material/object will use the same color?

The main benefit from this technique is that it's anti-aliased which makes it more suitable for masking.

Answer (score 1):

Each material can have it's own *Pass Index* set up in the *Properties Window > Material > Settings > Pass Index*

If you set them up correctly after rendering, using a *Compositor* you can use an *ID Mask* node to mask out each part of the image according to material.

It can be directly from the *Render Layers* node or from an *Image* node through a multi layer file format like EXR.

[See the Blender Manual on how to](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/converter/id_mask.html?highlight=pass%20index)

You an then use the compositor to extract one mask for each material and save it as an image.

This technique has the advantage that since it uses a black and white mask for each layer pass you can get full anti-aliasing for each mask, without running the risk of 'ID Collision' when the mixed anti-aliased colors match a different object from another pass.

Comment: I don't believe the ID masks are anti-aliased? The ID node in the compositor has some sort of "anti alias" option but it's never worked well for me.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28917/accurate-indexob-and-indexma-passes

Comment: Hum never really tested it myself, but there seem to be some nice workarounds in the answer linked by poor

Comment: Thanks for the input but unfortunately I'm not looking for a workaround.
Also I'm not so much looking to isolate every single object into a sepperate black and white mask because this would be extremely time concuming if you have a complex scene with lots of objects.
I only want to render out a collored map wich in turn could be used in photoshop to quickly mask out parts of the image.
End use: Architectural visualisation

Comment: Maybe you could set it up in the compositor in such a way that the per-material masks would be automatically combined into a color mask of your choice. It still takes some work to set up, but you only have to do it once, then all you have to is re-save it whenever you update your scene.