# Is it possible to get Material ID passes with Anti-aliasing rather than jagged edges?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, render-passes

I cannot get a clean anti-aliased material id pass which makes selecting in photoshop a nightmare. 
Anyone has an answer to this ?

Comment: As of 2.8x you can use [cryptomatte](https://github.com/Psyop/Cryptomatte)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accurate IndexOB and IndexMA passes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28917/accurate-indexob-and-indexma-passes)