# One Render layer with a transparent background and one with sky?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

How do you get one render layer to have a transparent background 
and the other to have a sky?
I mean in the shading panel where it says "Alpha: Transparent (or) Sky"

Comment: I think you may have to use different scenes instead of render layers, like [this method](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19422/5705) for rendering a pass with no DoF.

Comment: I am afraid that wont be possible, because I have to use the same camera  movements from the original scene in the exact same place.

Comment: You can link the same camera object to both scenes and it will follow the same animation and have all the same settings.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the Sky option on.

### [image]

Then make two render layers. One with The sky option enabled.

[image]

And one without it:

[image]

The one with the sky disabled will have a transparent background.

[image]